# Qual a diferença de "nó", "atributo", "elemento" e "tag" em XML?

Tags: xml, terminologia, característica-linguagem

Estou confuso a respeito de algumas características e termos da linguagem de marcação XML que são: ***nó***, ***atributo***, ***elemento*** e ***tag***, eu gostaria de saber o que é cada um deles e quais são as diferenças entre eles?

Segue este XML para ajudar na explicação e servi como exemplo:

```
<alunos>
    <aluno>
        <nome>Dener</nome>
        <nota1>7</nota1>
        <nota2>8</nota2>
        <nota3>5</nota3>
        <nota4>10</nota4>
    </aluno>

    <aluno>
        <nome>Raphael</nome>
        <nota1>8</nota1>
        <nota2>6</nota2>
        <nota3>6</nota3>
        <nota4>9</nota4>
    </aluno>

    <aluno>
        <nome>Ana</nome>
        <nota1>5</nota1>
        <nota2>6</nota2>
        <nota3>4</nota3>
        <nota4>5</nota4>
    </aluno>
</alunos>
```

Comment: pergunta facilmente respondida pelo google, logo de inicio, encontrei esse material, veja se te serve:
http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/tutorial_xml-schema.php#.V6-kVLOVveQ

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho a ideia do site e trazer as explicações aqui para ficar disponível para a comunidade, eu li a respeito no google e msm assim continuo confuso sobre o assunto.

Comment: opa, sendo assim, então tá, Senhores moderadores, fica ao seu critério a minha sinalizção, de minha parte, com o comentario do autor, considero pertinent o assunto pois o mesmo realmente carece de maiores esclarecimentos

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho não é necessário sinalizar para algo que você mesmo pode fazer, esta iniciando no site, é normal. Pode deixar o comentário, ele servirá de fonte pra quem for responder. PS: as perguntas e respostas no site não servirão só para quem pergunta, mas para futuros usuários.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Nó** ou *node* é toda mínima parte do XML. Conjuntos de nós vão formando outros nós. Comparando, grosso modo, com linguagem de programação, são *tokens*. Alguns nós têm significado específico e alguns deles são descritos abaixo.

**Elemento** ou *element* é um bloco completo de dado e marcação que dá semântica ao dado. Ele inclui alguns dos nós descritos abaixo.

***Tag*** ou etiqueta é a marcação do que significa um determinado dado. Ela é sempre determinada por uma palavra dentro do sinal `<>`. Pode haver uma *tag* que abre o bloco e uma que fecha. Algumas são *auto fechantes*.

Algumas *tags* podem ter algumas informações específicas que dão melhor semântica aos dados que estão contidos nelas, são chamados de **atributo** (*attribute*). Normalmente é um par de chave (indicando sobre que está se falando ali) e valor (o que informa o atributo), mas existem os que são apenas chave.

Ainda existe o texto dentro de determinadas *tags* que são os dados. Do ponto de vista do XML sempre é um texto. Se o dado for de algum outro tipo que mereça uma conversão, será determinado pela *tag* e seus atributos, ou ainda por um *schema* que configure isso e uma aplicação que sabe como interpretá-lo melhor (muito comum).

Então

```
<nota1>7</nota1>
```

Há um dado `7` que, claro, é um nó. Há um par de *tags* encapsulando esse nó dando a semântica que isso é a `nota 1`. Tudo isso junto forma outro nó. Este nó em específico é um elemento.

Não há atributos em todo o XML apresentado na pergunta. Mas poderia ser, sei lá, algo assim:

```
<nota1 prova=true>7</nota1>
```

`prova=true` é um atributo.

Tudo isto junto é outro nó:

```
<aluno>
    <nome>Dener</nome>
    <nota1>7</nota1>
    <nota2>8</nota2>
    <nota3>5</nota3>
    <nota4>10</nota4>
</aluno>
```

Todo o XML apresentado na pergunta é outro nó.

É comum as pessoas terem dificuldade em definir se algo deve ser um elemento ou só um atributo do elemento. É preciso entender o que é um dado (que é a parte fundamental de um elemento) e o que é apenas uma "decoração" do dado (o atributo). Esse atributo é igual ao do HTML, afinal o XML é muito parecido. De uma certa forma podemos dizer que o HTML é um XML especializado, e especificado para padronizar a web.

O *schema* é uma forma de indicar sua estrutura, definição do significado dos elementos possíveis, restrições e outras informações úteis para seu entendimento e sua manipulação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Com sua resposta finalmente entendi o motivo do XPath `text()` retornar tantos nós vazios entre elementos :D.

Answer (score 2):

Cada um dos [seguintes fragmentos](http://xahlee.info/js/javascript_DOM_confusing_terminology.html) de código abaixo:

```
<alunos>, <aluno>, <nome>, ...
```

São chamados de **tag**. Quanto temos elas "completas", com uma tag de início e uma tag do seu fim:

```
<alunos></alunos>, <aluno></aluno>, etc.
```

As chamamos de **elementos**.

Cada elemento pode ter zero, um ou mais atributos. No seu exemplo, nenhum deles tem atributo, mas apenas para exemplificar, poderíamos ter o **atributo** `id` em `<aluno>`:

```
<aluno id="aluno_1"></aluno>
```

Quanto o navegador (por exemplo) faz a leitura do XML/HTML ele o transforma em uma árvore [DOM](https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-o-dom-document-object-model/) (*Document Object Model*). [Quando isto ocorre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132579/2387977), cada elemento, atributo, texto entre outros tipos passam a ser chamados de **nó** (ou **objeto**).

Abaixo um [exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes.asp) de um DOM XML representado por uma árvore de nós (*node-tree*):

[image: Uma árvore de nós criada a partir de um XML]

Do seguinte XML:

```
<bookstore>
   <book category="cooking">
       <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
       <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
       <year>2005</year>
       <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```