# Editar valor dentro de um nó no XML com C#

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho um sistema de login no C# e um seguinte arquivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Usuarios>
    <Usuario>
        <User_ID>001</User_ID>
        <Password>010309</Password>
        <Password_Change_Date>00/00/00</Password_Change_Date>
        <User_Login>admteste</User_Login>
        <User_RG>00000002</User_RG>
        <User_Status>Normal</User_Status>
        <User_Profile>4</User_Profile>
    </Usuario>
    <Usuario>
        <User_ID>002</User_ID>
        <Password>01234</Password>
        <Password_Change_Date>01/10/2019</Password_Change_Date> 
        <User_Login>pbteste</User_Login>
        <User_RG>00000005</User_RG>
        <User_Status>Inicial</User_Status>
        <User_Profile>3</User_Profile>
    </Usuario>  
 </Usuarios>
```

Após o usuário fazer login, crio um objeto e guardo todos os dados dentro dos atributos deste objeto, minha dúvida é: Possuo uma página onde o usuário pode fazer a alteração de senha, como eu consigo fazer esta alteração dentro do arquivo XML no nó específico do usuário logado? Supondo que já tenho o User_ID salvo no objeto...
Obrigado

Comment: Se pode fazer a releitura do arquivo com XDocument e Linq e depois salvar novamente ...

Comment: Desculpe amigo, sou bem leigo com XML, poderia me dar algum exemplo simples por favor ?

Comment: Coloque o código que faz a leitura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de alterar um determinado nó de um documento XML é utilizando [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) para criar uma query e selecionar o nó que deseja alterar.

Neste caso, eu armazenei o nó em um [XmlNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmlnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) que serve para representar um único nó que foi mapeado em um XML, o nó foi retornado pelo método `SelectSingleNode()`, veja:

```
XmlNode noPassword = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Usuarios/Usuario[User_ID=" + "001" + "]/Password");
```

e fiz uma verificação para ver se não é nulo, antes te aplicar a mudança no nó especifico:

```
if (noPassword != null)
{
    noPassword.InnerText = "minha_nova_senha";              
}
```

Você pode salvar as mudanças no arquivo usando o método `Salve` da classe `XmlDocument` veja:

```
xmlDoc.Save(strMeuArquivo);
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrP6kP).

[Leitura complementar sobre XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147049/27190).

Comment: Esta verificação que é para ver se é nulo, é para ver se a query retornou algum resultado?  ps: Funcionou aqui, agradecido!